# If a batch program is added, do I have to create a new project?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

A batch program was implemented by creating a project different from the existing web project. I have a question here. If a batch program is added, do I have to create a project every time it is added or do I add it to the batch program project and manage it?

new project folder create